# Unable to change kube context

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

1. I run this AWS command to update my kubeconfig to point to a remote server. Everything works as expected and it's cool.

   ```
   aws --profile XXXXX eks update-kubeconfig --name ${1}
   Updated context arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:cluster/XXXXXXXX in /Users/gkXXXX/.kube/config
   ```
2. I run another command to update my kubeconfig to Minikube - BUT IT DOESN'T WORK. I have switched my context but still it doesn't work.

   ```
   gkhurana6@C ~ % kubectl config use-context minikube
   Switched to context "minikube".
   gkhurana6@C ~ % k get ns                           
   Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.64.29:8443: i/o timeout
   ```

The file `/.kube/config` is also updated

```
    gkhurana6@C ~ % cat /Users/gkhurana6/.kube/config

    ...
    current-context: minikube
    ...
```

Comment: Has the `minikube` context worked previously? Is the minikube cluster available?

Comment: Yeah, it used to work before. 
Yes, it is Minikube cluster